# Adding columns with django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django

How would I do the following in the django ORM:

```
cues = my_cues.filter(now__lte=date_expires).values('all' - 'remaining')
```

The equivalent of:

```
SELECT (all - remaining) FROM my_cues WHERE date_expires >= now()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using extra (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
cues = my_cues.filter(now__lte=date_expires).extra(
    select={'koko': 'all - remaining'}
).values('koko')
```